# How do I Concatenate an "*" asterisk into a vba formula

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to figure out how to concatenate an asterisk into a vba formula or a string for that matter.

[image]

it just always results in an error.

Comment: No problem with an asterisk - but you are missing the closing parenthesis?!

Comment: sorry my screenshot was cut, but it still produces an error

Comment: Please show an [mcve] of your problem. Also [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please insert the relevant code part as text formatted as code block.

Comment: What would you expect the formula to be? That code would result in something like `=SUMPRODUCT(D$2:D$5*)` if `LastUsdeRowOnOutputModelTabA = 5`. The formula does not make much sense to me and is not valid.

Comment: probably missing something before the *, `=SUMPRODUCT(D$2:D$12*)` would'nt be a valid formula anyway

Comment: The record macro button is your friend. Enter the formula manually in a cell and press Enter. Start recording, edit the cell with the formula by pressing F2, then just press Enter. Stop recording and you have the formula in the VBA editor. Then just use concatenation like you've already done to replace the row number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the concatenation outside the `sumproduct` formula. This should work:

```
TryOutputModelTab.Range("F2").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(D$2:D$" & LastUsedRowOnOutputModelTabA & ") & ""*"""
```